# Configuration Bean in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

This is regarding CDI spec of quarkus. Would want to understand is there a configuration bean for quarkus? How does one do any sort of configuration in quarkus?

Answer (score 2):

If I get it right the original question is about `@Configuration` classes that can contain `@Bean` definitions. If so then [CDI producer methods and fields](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi#ok-you-said-that-there-are-several-kinds-of-beans) annotated with `@javax.enterprise.inject.Produces` are the corresponding alternative.

Application configuration is a completely different question though and [Jay is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69108704/2654154) that the [Quarkus configuration reference](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference) is the ultimate source of information ;-).

Comment: Yes. Produces is an alternative for that correct. But it only has to be used for libs that are not yet merged with quarkus libs correct? for everything else - configuration happens in application.properties .Correct? !Updated the answer with @produces.

Answer (score 0):

First of all reading how cdi spec of quarkus differs from spring is important.

Please refer this guide:
https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference

The learnings from this guide is there is @Produces which is an alternative to @Configuration bean in Quarkus.

Let us take an example for libs that might require a configuration through code. Example: Microsoft Azure IOT Service Client.

```
public class IotHubConfiguration {


    @ConfigProperty(name="iothub.device.connection.string")
    String connectionString;


    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(IotHubConfiguration.class);

    @Produces
    public ServiceClient getIot() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        LOG.info("Inside Service Client bean");
        if(connectionString==null) {
            LOG.info("Connection String is null");
            throw new RuntimeException("IOT CONNECTION STRING IS NULL");
        }

        ServiceClient serviceClient = new ServiceClient(connectionString, IotHubServiceClientProtocol.AMQPS);
        serviceClient.open();
        LOG.info("opened Service Client Successfully");

        return serviceClient;
    }
```

For all libs vertically intergrated with quarkus application.properties can be used and then you will get a driver obj for that broker/dbs available directly through @Inject in your @applicationScoped/@Singleton bean  So, Why is that?

1. To Simplify and Unify Configuration
2. To Make Sure no code is required for configuring anything i.e. database config, broker config , quarkus config etc.

This drastically reduces the amount of code written for configuring and also Junits needed to cover that code.

Let us take an example  where  kafka producer  configuration needs to be added: in application.properties

```
kafka.bootstrap.servers=${KAFKA_BROKER_URL:localhost:9092}
mp.messaging.outgoing.incoming_kafka_topic_test.topic=${KAFKA_INPUT_TOPIC_FOR_IOT_HUB:input_topic1}
mp.messaging.outgoing.incoming_kafka_topic_test.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.outgoing.incoming_kafka_topic_test.value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
mp.messaging.outgoing.incoming_kafka_topic_test.key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
mp.messaging.outgoing.incoming_kafka_topic_test.health-readiness-enabled=true
```

For full blown project reference: https://github.com/JayGhiya/QuarkusExperiments/tree/initial_version_v1/KafkaProducerQuarkus

Quarkus References for Config:

https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference

Example for reactive sql config: https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients

Now let us talk about a bonus feature that quarkus provides which improves developer experience by atleast an order of magnitude that is profile driven development and testing.

Quarkus provides three profiles:

- dev - Activated when in development mode (i.e. quarkus:dev)
- test - Activated when running tests
- prod - The default profile when not running in development or test
  mode

Let us just say that in the given example you wanted to have different topics for development and different topics for production. Let us achieve that!

```
%dev.mp.messaging.outgoing.incoming_kafka_topic_test.topic=${KAFKA_INPUT_TOPIC_FOR_IOT_HUB:input_topic1}
%prod.mp.messaging.outgoing.incoming_kafka_topic_test.topic=${KAFKA_INPUT_TOPIC_FOR_IOT_HUB:prod_topic}
```

This is how simple it is. This is extremely useful in cases where your deployments run with ssl enabled brokers/dbs etc and for dev purposes you have unsecure local brokers/dbs. This is a game changer.